# How to make Xdebug only show backtrace when opening page, and not log the backtrace?

Tags: php, apache2, xdebug

Xdebug currently logs the entire backtrace in the defined error_log file:

```
CustomLog /var/log/www/access.log combined
ErrorLog /var/log/www/error.log
php_value error_log /var/log/www/error.log
```

This is fine. However, it logs too much. Ever since I installed Xdebug, it logs like this:

```
[02-May-2016 16:14:20 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: k in /var/www/index.php on line 30
[02-May-2016 16:14:20 Europe/Berlin] PHP Stack trace:
[02-May-2016 16:14:20 Europe/Berlin] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/index.php:0
```

This repeats about 10 times. I'm absolutely fine with just the error message like this:

```
[02-May-2016 16:14:20 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: k in /var/www/index.php on line 30
```

and having the full stack trace on the page when opening. Is it possible? I can't find any options related to logging just the message, and showing the trace on the page.

- PHP Version 5.6.4
- xdebug version 2.4.0

Comment: Can you share your xdebug configuration ?

Comment: Nothing changed - default as can be.

Comment: Checked https://xdebug.org/docs/stack_trace but found nothing to help :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After [XDebug](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings) docs:

```
xdebug.default_enable = 0
```

> Default value: 1
>
> If this setting is 1, then stacktraces will be shown by default on an error event. You can disable showing stacktraces from your code with xdebug_disable(). As this is one of the basic functions of Xdebug, it is advisable to leave this setting set to 1.

Where I would rather use somewhere at the beginning of script tree function of `xdebug_disable()` with a proper switch, to make it possible to turn it on and off, depening on the development state:

```
define('VERBOSE', /* from config/db/etc value of true/false */ false);
if(!VERBOSE) {
    xdebug_disable();
}
```

Will leave you a bit more flexibility if you have an admin holding your servers who won't be happy to change production environment configurations.

Comment: As there's apparently no other way of doing this, I'm going to go with this, and enabling Xdebug where I need it in the code. Thanks!